# How to add many Popovers in one View (iPad)?

Tags: ipad, popover

How exactly do you show many Popovers in one view? I'm trying to add many of them, just with different arrays.  I can show one using a delegate (the Popover has a separate view controller & it's nib).

Thanks

Comment: You might want to reconsider your UI design if it requires multiple popover to be visible at the same time!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's easy to stack them. I haven't tried running them in parallel, but this should work: create the first popover and add your current view to `passthroughViews`, then present the popover. Now you can start the next popover from you base view. Make sure you have a mechanism to dismiss the popovers later.